# What is the pen used by Francis Underwood (Kevin Spacey) to sign a document in House of Cards S02E13?

Tags: writing-instruments

At around the 26:50 mark of House of Cards S02E13, Francis Underwood (Kevin Spacey) signs a document. What make/model is the pen that he used?
Could be insufficient to answer, but here's the image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrWuv.jpg]

Comment: @weakdna [It was agreed on Meta](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1906/23927) that writing tool ID questions are on-topic here as long as they include an image, which this question does. OP originally asked this on Movies.SE, where it was closed as off-topic, and I personally redirected them here.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Cross Townsend, which is the model most Presidents use.
This one is probably the black or rarely-found titanium model.

---

Picture for comparison:
[image: Look at this thing. It costs 200 dollars!]

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Could you provide an image of a Cross Townsend pen for comparison?

Answer (score -4):

It's a Montblanc Meisterstuck 149 fountain pen

Took me less than a minute on Google to find this...
https://www.menchic.it/stile-uomo/kevin-spacey-di-house-of-cards-con-la-stilografica-montblanc-37174.html

Comment: You should've used the leftover seconds of that minute to look at OP's photo and see it's (probably) a ballpoint pen which looks nothing like the Montblanc Meisterstuck 149 with its prominent unhooded nib. The picture at your link is from some social event not associated with House of Cards.

Comment: I agree with @aniline that the image uploaded is not a fountain pen. However, taking cue from @robert’s answer I guess the pen is “Montblanc Meisterstück Platinum Classique Rollerball”

Comment: The pen in the image in the question is clearly NOT a fountain pen of any brand.  I own a number of them, and carry a cheap one every day.  I've used them since the early 1970s.